# Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128) on my discord bot on .setColor

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was coding an embed on my discord bot and then when I tried to run it the code gave me an error:

```
Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128) C:\Users\jerem\OneDrive\Desktop\AriaBot\index.js:23
                .setColor('#53BBFF')
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1018:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1066:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47`
```

I don't know what's wrong and here's my full code, can anyone help me out?

[image: picture one of my code]

[image: picture of my code half 2]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code but the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `;` after calling the `RichEmbed` constructor, essentially ending it.

What you have typed right now looks like this

```
const roleEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed();.setColor(...)
```

Remove the semicolon.